# How to converting Postgres code to Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I faced difficulty to convert the ff Postgres code to Snowflake. Can anyone help in this?

```
WITH sitel_users as (
          select
            user_id
          from validation_rep vr
          where true
            and (vr.feature_flags ->> 'is_bogota')::bool is true
        ), call_grade as (
          select
              aoc.user_id
            , (aocg.created_at at time zone 'z' at time zone 'us/central')::date as call_grade_date
            , avg(aocg.score) call_grade_avg
          from asterisk_outbound_call_grade aocg
            join asterisk_outbound_call aoc on aocg.asterisk_outbound_call_id = aoc.id
          where true
            and aocg.deleted_at is null
            and aocg.created_at >= current_date::timestamp at time zone 'us/central' - interval '7 days'
            and exists(select 1 from sitel_users su where aoc.user_id = su.user_id)
          group by 1,2
```

Comment: You'll generally get more responsiveness and more accurate answers by including a small sample of input data and an example of what the output data should be. It may be possible to convert between SQL dialects without this, but it makes it easier with sample data and verifies correctness with intended output.

Comment: And if having "difficulty" - what's the difficult part? What error messages do you get? For any specific error message, we could work that as a simpler question (instead of having us rewrite the whole query without data to work with)

Comment: The errors I got include: 1. (vr.feature_flags ->> 'is_bogota')::bool is true ; 2. (aocg.created_at at time zone 'z' at time zone 'us/central')::date as call_grade_date ; 3. (aocg.created_at at time zone 'z' at time zone 'us/central')::date as call_grade_date

Answer (score 0):

I don't think rewriting this SQL can be done without checking/touching data because the incompatible SQL is related to data and TZ conversions. Anyway, this one may be a good start for you:

```
WITH sitel_users as (
          select
            user_id
          from validation_rep vr
          where true
           and vr.feature_flags:VARCHAR = 'is_bogota'
           /* and (vr.feature_flags ->> 'is_bogota')::bool is true */
        ), call_grade as (
          select
              aoc.user_id
            , convert_timezone( 'America/Chicago', convert_timezone( 'UTC', d )  )::DATE  as  call_grade_date
             /* (aocg.created_at at time zone 'z' at time zone 'us/central' )::date   as  call_grade_date */
            , avg(aocg.score) call_grade_avg
          from asterisk_outbound_call_grade aocg
            join asterisk_outbound_call aoc on aocg.asterisk_outbound_call_id = aoc.id
          where true
            and aocg.deleted_at is null
            and aocg.created_at >= convert_timezone('America/Chicago', current_date ) - interval '7 days' 
            /*  and aocg.created_at >= current_date::timestamp at time zone 'us/central' - interval '7 days' */
            and exists(select 1 from sitel_users su where aoc.user_id = su.user_id)
          group by 1,2
```

Comment: Thank you Gokhan. You are right, it's difficult to modify the code w/o data. However, the change you made greatly helpful.